# Need help finding a standardquote about reserved Identifiers in C++

Tags: c++

The coding convention at the company I'm working for requires to let any private member variable have the prefix `_`.
I know that it is forbidden in plain C and I also know the text from the ISO/IEC:9899 where it is stated as reserved.

I was looking up in the N3690 document for finding anything stating about it, but I couldn't find.
So I wasn't able to find anything that forbids me using this prefix in C++ standard, but I might just have overlooked something that was stated like "C++ behaves in regards to ........ same as mentioned in the C standard section....."

So I'm just asking you for helping me finding the exact phrase for C++ (11 preferred) that is reserving the `_` same as it is in C.

Since C++ implements libraries and all this stuff from C, it feels wrong using identifier in C++ that are explicitly stated as reserved in C.
But for criticizing our coding convention I should at least be able to find a base against it, but currently I'm just able to argue.
(And can't even verify that I'm right so far regardless of I couldn't imagine that I'm wrong.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does it say that in the C standard?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: note that it's ok to have an identifier that starts with a single underscore followed by a lower case letter if that identifier is not in a global scope (like in a class)

Comment: @PiotrS. : regardless of it is private or not?

Comment: @Zaibis access scope is irrelevant

Comment: Even in C, those are reserved only at file scope unless the underscore is followed by an uppercase letter or another underscore.